# How does Mercurial handle splitted files?

Tags: mercurial, merge, filesplitting

How does mercurial handle splitted files? What will happen if I create a branch and split a file. Can I easily pull changes from another branch which modifies the original, unsplitted file?

Comment: What do you mean by "splitted files"?  Do you mean that you create a branch and then split the contents of the file into two new files?  Or do you just mean changing the file in both branches?

Comment: I am into programming and plan to split a God class into several smaller classes.

This means I want to split the content of the god-class-file within my branch into several other files.
I'd like to know if mercurial can then apply chunks/changes which were made in the original file (in the default branch), to e.g. a function which now resides in another file in my refactoring branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the clarification comment, the answer is no.  Mercurial tracks files, not hunks of code, so it can't do that as far as I know.

Answer (score 7):

I just did a little experiment.  I created one repository (`foo`) with one big file.  Then I cloned that into `bar`, used `hg cp` to copy the file into two files, and removed one half in both files.  Then I made a change affecting the whole file in `foo`, and merged that into `bar`.

As a result, the parts contained by the respective split file were merged correctly, while I got a conflict for the removed parts: my local version was empty, while the other version was the change from `foo`.

So if you're happy with removing these kinds of conflicts every time you merge, this might be good enough for you.